# Rails 3.1 : can? Method always returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have a problem with my rails-App. I use cancan to hide some links from certain users.
I don´t get any errors and the role of the user is correctly recognized. But whatever I try, my link is never shown. The can?-Method always returns true.
This is my ability class:

```
 class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

 def initialize(user)

   current_user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
   puts "Debug"
   if current_user.role?(:Admin)
     can :manage, Prof
   else 
     if current_user.role?(:Proff)
       can :manage, [Exam, Note, Student,Break,Appointment]
     else 
       if current_user.role?(:Student)
         can :update, Appointment
         can :show, Exam
       end
     end
   end
  end
end
```

This is from my view: the @exam is definitly not nil. I also tried Exam and :exam, nothing works.

```
<% if can? :edit, @exam%>
  <%= link_to 'Bearbeiten', edit_exam_path(@exam) %> |
  <%= link_to 'Alle Prüfungen', exams_path %>
<% end%>
```

I don´t know, if this is important, but thats the head of my controller:

```
class ExamsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :login_required
   skip_authorization_check
   ...
```

My Exam Model:

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :prof

  validates_presence_of :prof_id,:title,:deadline
  has_many :examdates, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :examdates, 
      :allow_destroy => true#, :reject_if => proc {| a| a[:date].blank? }
end
```

In the console I tried

```
 Exam.accessible_by(ability)
```

and got [].
I´m using cancan 1.6.7, rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.8.7.

I really hope, someone can figure out, what I´m doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if current_user.role?(:Proff)`shouldn't it be `if current_user.role?(:Prof)`?

Comment: No, I just named the Role, with two ffs, because I have a model Prof, aswell and didn´t want any conflicts. Not sure if it is nessecary.

Comment: isn't this `skip_authorization_check` skipping authorization check???

Comment: in the console you need to try: `user = User.first` then `Exam.accessible_by(user)`

Comment: Yes, I removed it, but there is still no difference. The can?-Method returns always false, no matter for which User. With the load_and_authorize_resource in the controller I cant get to the show view. I really don´t know why. The role? returns true, so it should work.

Comment: In the console I tried what you suggested and got []. Also with the admin- User and the Prof Model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it should be all good by adding

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

in the controller.
 By this, `@exam` is already loaded and authorized in every action in the controller.
I know that you can also pass the class instead of an instance, so `Exam` should work, but still try my solution.

Also look at [Debugging-Abilities-Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Debugging-Abilities)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try load_and_authorize resource I get an error: The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:3000/ has resulted in too many redirects. Even if i put :exam behind it. This will result with and without the additional skip_authorization_check. I tried to debug the abilities as described on the link, but I just got that, the user isn´t allowed to do the things I allowed him with can.

Comment: Okay, I got rid of the redirect-problem. It was in my controller and I skipped the authorization of the index action. Anyway I now cannot get to the show view and get the access-denied-message from cancan. I think the problem is still the same, why are the abilities I give to the user not recognized?

Comment: Can you post your controller code and your Cancan Ability class and any other helper functions that you are using associated with it, to have a look at. Upload gists of them and post links to it here.

Comment: I finally got it. I had to change the current_user to just user in my ability-class. I´m still not sure, why, but I have a controller-authentication-module, which defines a current_user method. Must have something to do with each other. Thanks anyway!